# 'jquery.tabledit' Js multiple inline edit in one column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used 'jquery.tabledit.js' library for inline edit. It's working fine if one value edit in one column. I want multiple values edit in one column.

I tried lots but not work for me.

Kindly Provide me help.

Thanks

Comment: As you are new in stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
$('#example1').Tabledit({
    url: 'example.php',
    columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [[1, 'nickname'], [2, 'firstname'], [3, 'lastname']]
    }
});
```

You can benefit from the links here:http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples